# Not sending Firebase events with null values to BigQuery

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to not send Firebase events with null values to BigQuery? Is it possible to normalize it?

In the picture below you can see the null values in BigQuery.
[image]

**Flutter Code:**

```
  final analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  analytics.logEvent(name: eventName, parameters: params);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `removeWhere` to filter out null values prior to logging the event.

```
params.removeWhere((k, v) => v == null);
if (params.isNotEmpty) {
  analytics.logEvent(name: eventName, parameters: params);
}
```

Comment: Client-side there are no null values. I think that the null values will be created from BigQuery.

Comment: What are you using to send events to BigQuery?

Comment: The firebase_analytics flutter package (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics). The logEvent method is from 'FirebaseAnalytics.instance'.

Comment: Considering it's a free-form object for `logEvent`, I'm not sure how nulls could be inserted between your code and BigQuery unless they are in the object you are passing in for `params`.

Comment: Printing out the params does not show any null value. I can't control the string_value, float_value and double_value properties.

Comment: Could you update to include more of your code? Being able to see how you populate the params would help.